# firebase init functions - "functions" folder is not being created

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I create my app with flutter, firebase. I wanna use cloud functions. so I try `firebase init functions` in my terminal. but "functions" folder is not being created. What should I do to make it work correctly? Here's a picture of my terminal below, please take a look for reference.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: My bet is simply just permissions - it does not have access to write in this directory.  Also, as the warning says, maybe it is worth adapting the node version.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase functions have specific Node.js runtime requirements. Check the Firebase documentation to find out which version of Node.js is officially supported for the version of Firebase you are using. If the required Node.js version is not installed, you will need to install it.

For any further reference you can follow the the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=1st).